# Select tag which are not already selected as descendants of the same elements

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

using BeautifulSoup, I'd like to select all the tables with class "main" which are not already selected as descendants of the same elements.
In lxml, the following code works:

```
root.xpath('//table[@class="main" and not(ancestor::table[@class="main"])]')
```

But how can I do this in BeautifulSoup?

Thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably not the most efficient solution, but it should work:

```
nested_tables = soup.select('table.main table.main')
tables = [t for t in soup.select('table.main') if t not in nested_tables]
```

You could also do it this way:

```
tables = [t for t in soup.select('table.main') 
          if not t.find_parents('table', class_='main')]
```